# Frozen Touchpad when I'm using more than one actor with touchpad in stage

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

I have written a game with [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com) in android via RoboVM. After migration to [Multi-OS Engine](https://software.intel.com/en-us/multi-os-engine), everything is OK except using `Touchpad` and firepad in iOS version, that they going to frozen if I touch them together. I think the main problem is that LibGDX cannot handle multi touch in iOS version. By adding `Gdx.app.log` in touchDown and touchUp override method I found that if I touch both of touchpads, touchUp method never call until next touch them again.
My code is like this:

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    stage = new Stage();
    private void initTouchPad() {
        Touchpad.TouchpadStyle touchpadStyle;
        Skin touchpadSkin;
        Drawable touchBackground;
        Drawable touchKnob;

        touchpadSkin = new Skin();
        //Set background image
        touchpadSkin.add("touchBackground", new Texture("touchBackground.png"));
        //Set knob image
        touchpadSkin.add("touchKnob", new Texture("touchKnob.png"));
        touchpadStyle = new Touchpad.TouchpadStyle();
        //Create Drawable's from TouchPad skin
        touchBackground = touchpadSkin.getDrawable("touchBackground");
        touchKnob = touchpadSkin.getDrawable("touchKnob");
        touchKnob.setMinWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6/3);
        touchKnob.setMinHeight(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6/3);
        //Apply the Drawables to the TouchPad Style
        touchpadStyle.background = touchBackground;
        touchpadStyle.knob = touchKnob;
        //Create new TouchPad with the created style
        touchpad = new Touchpad(10, touchpadStyle);
        //setBounds(x,y,width,height)
        float touchPadSize = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 6;
        if(MainGame.FireButton)
            touchpad.setBounds(touchPadSize*5 , 15, touchPadSize, touchPadSize);
        else
            touchpad.setBounds(15, 15, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6);
        touchpad.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                Gdx.app.log("toudhpad", "touch down");
                touchPadTouched = true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                touchPadTouched = false;
                Gdx.app.log("toudhpad", "touch up");

            }
        });
        stage.addActor(touchpad);

    }


private void initFirePad() {
    Touchpad.TouchpadStyle touchpadStyle;
    Skin touchpadSkin;
    Drawable touchBackground;

    touchpadSkin = new Skin();
    //Set background image
    Texture fireTexture = new Texture("fire_button.png");
    touchpadSkin.add("touchBackground", fireTexture);
    touchpadStyle = new Touchpad.TouchpadStyle();
    //Create Drawable's from TouchPad skin
    touchBackground = touchpadSkin.getDrawable("touchBackground");
    //Apply the Drawables to the TouchPad Style
    touchpadStyle.background = touchBackground;
    //Create new TouchPad with the created style
    firePad = new Touchpad(10, touchpadStyle);
    //setBounds(x,y,width,height)
    float firePadSize = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 6;

    if(MainGame.FireButton)
        firePad.setBounds(15, 15, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6);
    else
        firePad.setBounds(firePadSize*5 , 15, firePadSize, firePadSize);
    firePad.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("firepad", "touch down");
            firePadTouched = true;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("firepad", "touch up");
            firePadTouched = false;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(firePad);
}
```